# Ag-grid valueGetter does not fire when "Column" is out of view or hidden

Tags: calculated-columns, ag-grid-angular

Use: We use ag-grid like we would use excel on our client software. In it we have some custom calculations that I run with the valueGetter function. Our grid has over 50 ColumnDefs. This means that some of the columns are not in view until you scroll right or left respectively. All my functions work and I have no calculation issues.

Issue: When I edit a Value I have some columns that now need to fire the valueGetter. For the columns that are currently in view they fire and run the calcs without issues, however there are some columns that are out of view and some columns are hidden. On these specifically the grid will not run the value getter until it is in view or the hidden flag on the column has been set to false.

The main reason for this being an issue is that because the grid is so wide I have to hide and show certain columns as a "view Groups". I need to know if there is a gridOptions setting or grid Directive that I am missing? Or is there another solution where I can have the calculations for the entire runs when I edit a field.

ag-grid version 23.0.2
angular version 8

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using Adaptable with your AG Grid implementation but if you are then this might help:

We had this issue a while back and we solved it by moving the custom calculations out of AG Grid and into Adaptable's Calculated Columns which will evaluate whenever any relevant cell in the row updates.

Comment: thanks for this, this exactly what we need.